# Finding all zeros of continous function on given interval

Tags: functions, algorithms, roots

If we have an arbitrary continuous function (but not necessarily with continuous derivative), how can we find all zeros of this function on a given interval ? Is there perhaps an algorithm similar to bisection method ?

Comment: How is the "arbitrary continuous function" given to you?

Comment: If you have no additional information about the continuous function, you cannot find out the zeros. There can be $0$ ($f(x)=1$) over many ($f(x)=(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)$) over countably infinite ($f(x)=\sin(x)$) over uncountably many ($f(x)=0$)